# Bash - how to write the output of a command into a variable and also get the commands pid

Tags: bash, shell, process

I need to get the full output of a command and also get its pid. The problem is that getting the pid works like this:

```
(nmcli d wifi connect "$1" password "$2") & PID=$!
```

and grabbing the output works like this:

```
output="$(nmcli d wifi connect $1 password $2)"
```

How do I combine these two?

Comment: I don't see how the PID is any use once you have captured the output, as the child process no longer exists by that point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use a temporary file:

```
f="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/tmp.$$"
trap "rm $f" EXIT
nmcli d wifi connect "$1" password "$2" >"$f" &
nm_pid=$!

# ... do stuff

wait $nm_pid
# ... use contents of "$f"
```

(I've added quotes around your $1 and $2 - it's rare to encounter *too much quoting* in scripts).

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```
#/bin/env bash
nmcli d wifi connect "$1" password "$2" > /tmp/$$.tmp &
PID=$!
wait
output=$(</tmp/$$.tmp)
...
```

Comment: yes, but is this not possible without writing into a tmp file?

Comment: @RichiBurkhardt: i don't think so. At least, I don't know how.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done. You want to run program in background and capture it's output simultaneously into a variable. If that would be possible then the value of the variable would be changing during the execution of background program without your explicit commands. For example:

```
output="$(nmcli d wifi connect $1 password $2)" &
echo $output #maybe empty
sleep 10
echo $output #what now?
```

In the above script we did not change the value of "output" variable explicitly (by assignment). But if the feature you are asking about would be possible then the value of the variable would change implicitly (which is error-prone).

You can achieve same functionality by redirecting output of a background command to a file.

Comment: i actually have the "async" logic runnung. only capturing the errors it not possible.